# Edit and view BibTex database on Android

Tags: bibliographies, android

I found many applications which claim to a reference manager for Android. Some of which are:

- [RefMaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.bares.refmaster) (removed from AppStore),
- [Library](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgogolin.library) (last edit on [Github](https://github.com/cgogolin/library) in 2018),
- [Erasthotenes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mm.eratos) (removed from AppStore).

Which one do you use which works with OwnCloud, uses the BibTex Format and can handle links to PDF files similar to JabRef?

Comment: Too sad, that two of the linked apps do not exists anymore and Library is the only one left but the last commits on github are already a few years ago.
Are there any new apps to test? It seems that Library does the job right but for example it can not display stars/tags/comments from JabRef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research, unfortunately there is no reference manager for Android that can handle reading Bibtex, handle PDF file links AND synchronize with Owncloud.

However, I am quite satisfied with my solution that is as follows:

- I use RefMaster to handle the Bibtex file and suppports PDF file links
- I save my Bibtex file on the local memory and use a synchronization app to keep it up to date with the file in my Owncloud. A suitable app for this would be e.g. "FolderSync Lite" (no need to pay the full version for these needs). For me unfortunately, I couldn't connect to my Owncloud server with this app for any unknown reason. That's why I personally use "Synchronize Ultimate" that syncs Owncloud with my local memory but only does this on demand. This simply means that there is no Daemon running that keeps the Bibtex file always synchronous with the file in my Owncloud. However, this solution is the best I could achieve until now.

Please let me know whether you find an even better solution, I would be very interested! Please also let me know whether your "FolderSync Lite" works with your Owncloud server.

Comment: FolderSync Lite does work for me. I am using Sciebo as the cloud service which is basically a university hosted ownCloud-server. Do you use RefMaster on your computer then?

Comment: On my computer I am using JabRef to organize my library

Answer (score 1):

I'm also work in JabRef in my Ubuntu PC and tried to find android app to manage my reference. I created my own application at (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pulsardev.com.bibref)

Please feel free to drop by and leave me a message if you need any further function. I'm going to updated the app very soon!

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, your app seems to be not in playstore anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try BibTex Manager for Android

It can handle pdf files and links. You need to synchronize your bibtex file and zotero storage on pc.

[Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.eu.thedoc.bibtexmanager)